# Align indent to parenthesis after linebreak in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I like to keep my lines below 80 columns, so I often want to refactor a line that looks like this:

```
object.function(a_long_argument, another_long_argument, and_a_third)
```

to this:

```
object.function(a_long_argument,
                another_long_argument,
                and_a_third)
```

But when I press Enter after the first "," in Sublime it just linebreaks and indents the cursor a few spaces. I want it to align to the paranthesis or [] or {} that I am in, like Emacs does so beautifully.

Is there an option for this? Is there a plugin for this? Do I have to write my own?

I have tried searching for it, but I have not found anything.

EDIT:

Even better would be a shortcut or plugin or something for selecting a few rows, or the entire buffer, and let it try to auto-linebreak at good spots. Refactor comments too. If it has to be language specific, I want it primarily for Python and C++.

Comment: I'd like to know this as well.  Consider asking Jon (the developer of ST2), directly, over on the [Sublime Forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/) if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: Thanks @AGS, I will do that if no one answers in 24 hours or so. I figured that since Stackoverflow has a tag for sublime text, he would be lurking here.

Comment: For formatting whole Python files according to PEP-8 you can use PyTidy https://github.com/witsch/SublimePythonTidy

Comment: OK, now I have asked on the forum as well: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9182

Comment: You can make it syntax specific by using Settings > Settings - More > Syntax Specific - User

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sublime's `indent_to_bracket` will wrap the cursor for you. Just add the following line to either your `User/Preferences.sublime-settings` or `User/Python.sublime-settings` file:

```
"indent_to_bracket": true
```

Unfortunately this currently only seems to work with parentheses, curly braces and square brackets still wrap to the previous line indent.